# Substr in sql oracle

Tags: string, sql

I've just found this query in a script:

```
... WHERE (utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr( soamsg,2000,1)) LIKE '%BWXX0011%' )
OR (utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr( soamsg,2000,2001)) LIKE '%BWXX0011%' )
```

I'm not really use to SQL oracle, but I guess it should do the search in soamsg from char 1 to 2000 and then from 2001 to 4000.
Anyway, I thought the subsr pattern was : (string, position, length), if so, there is in error in the above query?

Am I confusing something?

Comment: I think your question doesn't belong here but on a more DB focus stackexchange eventually

Comment: Oracle or not, it's fairly obvious that you won't find `BWXX0011` in `123BWXX0011456` if you split it in `123BWXX` and `0011456`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to know a function signature is to [look it up in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i999349):

> ```
> DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (
>    lob_loc     IN    BLOB,
>    amount      IN    INTEGER := 32767,
>    offset      IN    INTEGER := 1)
>   RETURN RAW;
>
> DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (
>    lob_loc     IN    CLOB   CHARACTER SET ANY_CS,
>    amount      IN    INTEGER := 32767,
>    offset      IN    INTEGER := 1)
>   RETURN VARCHAR2 CHARACTER SET lob_loc%CHARSET;
>
> DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR (
>    file_loc     IN    BFILE,
>    amount      IN    INTEGER := 32767,
>    offset      IN    INTEGER := 1)
>   RETURN RAW;
> ```
>
> - `lob_loc` Locator for the LOB to be read. For more information, see Operational Notes.
> - `file_loc` The file locator for the LOB to be examined.
> - `amount` Number of bytes (for BLOBs) or characters (for CLOBs) to be read.
> - `offset` Offset in bytes (for BLOBs) or characters (for CLOBs) from the start of the LOB (origin: 1).

So your assumption was wrong.